# Can an android app call from a database stored on google app engine?

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine

I have no experience with hosting android app databases on google app engine and would like to know if the following is possible:

users upload files to the global database stored on app engine. the user sees a stream of the latest files added to the database on his android device.

While I am sure the concept is achievable, I am asking specifically if google app engine is the right tool for this task?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Applications don't call databases directly.

You have to write a small interface (API) on your google-app-engine server in any of your favorite language that returns either JSON or XML data. You can call that google-app-engine interface url, pass your parameters and get result in either XML or JSON.

Then you can parse that data in your application and show results.

Comment: An API on App Engine can also easily be achieved using [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/) (optionally combined with the [Endpoints Proto Datastore API](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/). It can [auto-generate an Android client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android) based off of the application's API.